# Change hover effect

Tags: html, css

I bought this template a couple of days ago and there is a hover effect which I would like to change. Right now is it like this , that you see couple of pics and if you go with your mouse over it , it will hover ( in gold and some text ) . What im trying is that I would like to change it. I would like to have it at first in this gold way and after you go with the mouse over it , it should be clear.

I'm sitting now since three days on it and I dont know what to do. There are so many script files.

```
<div class="portfolio-item border portrait fashion">
    <div class="portfolio-item-hover">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <div class="portfolio-item-hover-info">
            <hr/>
            <h3>Schuppenflechten</h3>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is one of the html code and on this page you can see my problem. It would be very nice if you can help me [test](http://devel.dermatologie-am-dom.de/allgemeine_dermatologie/)

Comment: 2 Hints: 1. The hover effect is coming from css. 2. use browser debugger to see from what file the effect is coming. After this you can just overwrite the original hover effect with your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.portfolio-item-hover {

 opacity: 0;

}
```

change opacity to .9 here.

and

```
.portfolio-item: hover {
 opacity: .9;
}
```

chage opacity to 0 here.

It works..

Answer (score 0):

In your css file fineliner.css, line 836, look for the following

```
.portfolio-item:hover .portfolio-item-hover {
    opacity: 0.9; //change this to 0
}

.portfolio-item-hover {
    background: #C5AE87;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0; //change this to 0.9
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    transition: opacity .18s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .18s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .18s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: opacity .18s ease-in-out;
}
```

That's it